# Last hard disk partitioning date?

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning

I want to find out when my Windows XP PC's HDD was last partitioned.

Is there a partition table creation date?

Answer (score 2):

No.

A [master boot record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) contains boot code (never changes), the four partition entries, and a signature or two. No dates.

Since the MBR can be modified after booting off a CD or even with another computer, I don't see any guaranteed (or merely likely) way you can deduce the date either. Running a disk/partition editor does not mean the partition table was modified.